# Google API authentication in Java without using environment variable

Tags: java, google-api

I have set up a simple test app to interact with Google's [Natural Language API](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/). I [created a service account](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/docs/common/auth#set_up_a_service_account), and downloaded the JSON credentials. I am running on a local development machine, so I set the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable to point to the JSON file. To be clear, *this works*: the app successfully makes some API calls and displays the results.

I would like to remove the dependence on the environment variable. How can I use the known location of the JSON file (or any other approach) in the application to create the `LanguageServiceClient` with those credentials?

Answer (score 3):

You can register is like this:

```
DatastoreOptions options = DatastoreOptions.newBuilder()
  .setProjectId(PROJECT_ID)
  .setAuthCredentials(AuthCredentials.createForJson(
    new FileInputStream(PATH_TO_JSON_KEY))).build();
```

Does that help?

Comment: What I need is a `LanguageServiceClient`. Can you get me from `DatastoreOptions` to `LanguageServiceClient`?

Answer (score 3):

Following the advice from *tokyohans* answer above, I can confirm this works for LanguageServiceClient:

```
    // old-school Google Authentication     
    GoogleCredential credential = null;
    credential = GoogleCredential.fromStream(new FileInputStream("google.json"));

    Collection<String> scopes = Collections.singleton("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-language");

    if (credential.createScopedRequired()) {
          credential = credential.createScoped(scopes);
    }

    // copy over key values, note the additional "s", set some expiry
    // com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials 
    GoogleCredentials sac = ServiceAccountCredentials.newBuilder()
                .setPrivateKey(credential.getServiceAccountPrivateKey())
                .setPrivateKeyId(credential.getServiceAccountPrivateKeyId())
                .setClientEmail(credential.getServiceAccountId())
                .setScopes(scopes)
                .setAccessToken(new AccessToken(credential.getAccessToken(), new LocalDate().plusYears(1).toDate()))
                .build();

    // Latest generation Google libs, GoogleCredentials extends Credentials
    CredentialsProvider cp = FixedCredentialsProvider.create(sac);
    LanguageServiceSettings settings = (LanguageServiceSettings) LanguageServiceSettings.newBuilder().setCredentialsProvider(cp).build();
    return LanguageServiceClient.create(settings);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can always pass the full json file as String as follows:

```
        CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider;
        String credentials = "[YOUR JSON FILE CONTENT]";

        try {

            credentialsProvider
                    = FixedCredentialsProvider.create(
                            ServiceAccountCredentials.fromStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(credentials.getBytes())));          

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(GoogleNLPService.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        LanguageServiceSettings.Builder languageServiceSettingsBuilder
                = LanguageServiceSettings.newBuilder();

        LanguageServiceSettings languageServiceSettings = languageServiceSettingsBuilder.setCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider).build();

        List<NamedEntity> entities = new ArrayList<>();
        try (LanguageServiceClient language = LanguageServiceClient.create(languageServiceSettings)) {

         ...

        }
```

Alternatively, you can place your json file in resources folder and then read it as:

```
    credentialsProvider
            = FixedCredentialsProvider.create(
                    ServiceAccountCredentials.fromStream(new FileInputStream("./src/main/resources/FILENAME.json")));
```

However, this relative path didn't work when I uploaded my app in Heroku. So, I have decided to use the String solution.

Answer (score 2):

We use a service account + `GoogleCredential.Builder` -- (note that this example uses a credential file in p12 format); example follows:

```
 private GoogleCredential authorize() throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException
{
    return new GoogleCredential.Builder()
    .setTransport(HTTP_TRANSPORT)
    .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
    .setServiceAccountId(serviceAccount)
    .setServiceAccountScopes(SCOPES)
    .setServiceAccountUser(serviceAccountUser)
    // variable p12File is a String w/ path to the .p12 file name
    .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new java.io.File(p12File))
      .build();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Steve. Can you get me from `GoogleCredential` to `LanguageServiceClient`? I'm just not seeing how to create a `LanguageServiceClient` with anything other than the application default credentials via the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable.

Comment: The docs for languageserviceclient allude to a CredentialsProvider (on the LanguageServiceSettings). I can't tie it all together off the top of my head, but I suspect you might need to make a credentials provider that "provides" your credentials (and see method I posted for an example of getting a Credential). That's my best guess just from a glance.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like an older thread but sharing our findings for what it's worth.

This example is for the Google ImageAnnotatorClient, but I am pretty sure it is very similar for LanguageServiceClient.

Old-school google libraries (P12 file era) use GoogleCredential vs. the new GoogleCredentials. They look very similar. Digging into the Type hierarchy I found a FixedCredentialsProvider which seems to do the trick.

This worked for us, we got the Google Vision API up and running with an existing P12 file without environment variable. It does look like Google wants us to migrate away from this so not recommending this approach long-term.

```
// old-school Google Authentication
HttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
JsonFactory jsonFactory = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

// Spring code
String pemFile = "yourPemFile.p12";
Resource r = new ClassPathResource(pemFile);
String serviceAccountEmail = "xxxx@xxxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com";

// com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential.Builder
Builder credentialBuilder = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
            .setTransport(httpTransport)
            .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
            .setServiceAccountId(serviceAccountEmail)
            .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(r.getFile());

// Cloud API endpoints, make sure that the API is enabled
Collection<String> scopes = Collections.singleton("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-vision");
GoogleCredential credential = credentialBuilder
            .setServiceAccountScopes(scopes).build();

// copy over key values, note the additional "s", set some expiry
// com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials 
GoogleCredentials sac = ServiceAccountCredentials.newBuilder()
            .setPrivateKey(gc.getServiceAccountPrivateKey())
            .setPrivateKeyId(gc.getServiceAccountPrivateKeyId())
            .setClientEmail(gc.getServiceAccountId())
            .setScopes(scopes)
            .setAccessToken(new AccessToken(gc.getAccessToken(), new LocalDate().plusYears(1).toDate()))
            .build();

// Latest generation Google libs, GoogleCredentials extends Credentials
CredentialsProvider cp = FixedCredentialsProvider.create(sac);
ImageAnnotatorSettings settings = ImageAnnotatorSettings.newBuilder().setCredentialsProvider(cp).build();
ImageAnnotatorClient googleApi = ImageAnnotatorClient.create(settings);
```